# How to get the difference between two rows in the same column

Tags: sql, clickhouse

This is what I have so far, I'm trying to get the difference between to rows in the same column. I can't figure it out. I'm trying to query in clickhouse.

```
SELECT 
    session_id,
    created,
    DATEDIFF(mi, time1.created, time2.created)
FROM impressions as time1
LEFT JOIN impressions i2 as time2
  ON time1.session_id = time2.session_id + 1
```

Comment: What “isn’t working” exactly? What are you expecting/wanting and what did you get?

Answer (score 3):

The query should use [dateDiff](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#datediff)-function:

```sql
SELECT 
    time1.session_id,
    time2.session_id,
    time1.created,
    dateDiff('minute', time2.created, time1.created)
FROM impressions AS time1
LEFT JOIN impressions AS time2 ON time1.session_id = toInt32(time2.session_id + 1)
SETTINGS join_use_nulls = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax in Clickhouse is:

```
SELECT time1.session_id, time1.created,
       DATEDIFF('minute', time2.created, time1.created)
FROM impressions time1 LEFT JOIN
     impressions i2 time2
     ON time1.session_id = time2.session_id + 1
```